# Make changes to the Edit Account Details page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Currently the Edit Account Details page have these fields: First Name, Last Name, Email address, Current Password & New Password. Now I need to overwrite the 'Save Changes' button which basically submits the form to update the user details. Before the form is being submitted, I want to do a javascript-based validation which checks the user's new password. How can I do this?

Btw I'm using WooCommerce, if that matters here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `woocommerce_edit_account_form_end` action to inject your custom `JS` snippet and do your validation.

like this

```
function add_my_account_edit_script() { ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("form.edit-account").submit(function(){

                    var old_pass = $("#password_1").val();
                    var new_pass = $("#password_2").val();

                    if( old_pass != new_pass ) {
                        // Show your validation message here
                        // return false to prevent the form submitting
                        return false;
                    }
                    // no validation error so allow the form to be submitted.
                    return false;

                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>   

    <?php 
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_end', 'add_my_account_edit_script' );
```